# managed c++ find and replace syntax

Tags: c++, mfc, isapi-redirect

I'm building an isapi filter that will grab any url requests with the prefix "http://localhost/" and redirect that url request to my message page  "http://localhost/default.html."

Here's the solution:

if(urlString.Find("/") != -1)
{
urlString.Replace(urlString, "/default.html");

Comment: what's wrong with the method you listed first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is: if(urlString.Find("/") != -1) { urlString.Replace(urlString, "/default.html");

Answer (score 2):

The boost string algorithm library has some effective replace [features](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3408550).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you may use a RegExp to do the job ! : [RegexLib.com](http://www.regexplib.com)